# React DropdownItem as Link only on desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say there is a have a Navbar that contains normal Items and DropdownItems.

I'm looking for the following behavior **when the user clicks the Dropdown**:
- On Destop it should Navigate to the Link (working),
- On Mobile it has to only open the Drpdown and NOT navigate.

Any idea how to do this?

```
{navItems.map((item, i) => (
    <Item key={i}>
        {(item.subItems)
            // if the item has subitems display dropdown
            ? <DropdownItemLinkMobileOnly to={item.path}>
                {item.label}
                <ChevronDown />
            </DropdownItemLinkMobileOnly>
            // if the item doesn't have subitems display as Link
        : <ItemLink to={item.path}>
            {item.label}
        </ItemLink>
        }                            
        {(item.subItems) &&
            //display the actual dropdown subitems
            <MenuDropdown items={item.subItems} />
        }
    </Item>
))}
```

Comment: What about adding a onclick event listener and putting logic there? You can use `this.props.history.push('///')` to redirect to a page.

Comment: The problem isn't with the router link. That works. It's detecting that the click came from mobilei need.